# Is there a way to display an excel sheet onto pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Not quite sure how to phrase this, but I have a database of information in Excel that I want to display to the pygame UI once they click a button. Anyone know if it is even possible, and how do I go about doing it?

The data is something as follows: [Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p1bR.png)

I've only managed to get this far:

```
MasterList = pd.read_csv(r'MasterList.csv')
def display_all():
ending = False
while not ending:
    display(MasterList)
    ending = True
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()            
    pygame.display.update()
```

But it only displays the excel sheet in the terminal but not the UI.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you display the data as a table?

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible. - If doing so makes sense, and how you'd go about doing so, can not be determined, as you have provided no information about either the data or the UI in question.

Comment: I'm so sorry I just inserted the table. I can only manage to get it to display on the terminal but not in the UI

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display it, you can try converting the worksheet to an image and then loading it into pygame.
Code from: https://blog.aspose.com/2021/05/28/convert-excel-to-image-in-python/

```
# load the Excel workbook
workbook = Workbook("Book1.xlsx")

# create image options
imgOptions = ImageOrPrintOptions()
imgOptions.setSaveFormat(SaveFormat.SVG)

# load the worksheet to be rendered
sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0)

# create sheet render object
sr = SheetRender(sheet, imgOptions)

# convert sheet to PNG image
for j in range(0, sr.getPageCount()):
    sr.toImage(j, "WorksheetToImage-out%s" %(j) + ".png")
```

After that, use `pygame.image.load()` and then `.blit()` it.